# How to call a batch file from antoher batchfile, and add their convars?

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking into starting a batch file, from another batch file, and having their convars be added on the way, like this:

We have **batch_1.bat**:

```
start program.exe -convar_x +variable_y 0 -convar_z
```

We have **batch_2.bat**:

```
start batch_1.bat -convar_a
```

I was hoping that when I run batch_2.bat I would get:

start program.exe -convar_x +variable_y 0 -convar_z -convar_a

But it seems it doesn't work like that. Do you know what syntax I could use to get this result?

Comment: Your problem, or question is unclear. As a guess, what if `batch_2.bat` was `@batch_1.bat -convar_a`, or `@call batch_1.bat -convar_a`, and `batch_1.bat` was `@start program.exe -convar_x +variable_y 0 -convar_z %1`, or `@start program.exe -convar_x +variable_y 0 -convar_z %*`?

Comment: Hey, adding "%*" to batch_1.bat did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: Is that a typo in `batch_2.bat`? Doesn't makes sense for a batch file to keep starting itself.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo in the question, it was meant to call batch_1